# Updating progress bar during copying a large file size

Tags: qt, qfile

How to update the progress bar to show the progress of copying a file because `QFile` documentation says:

> Unlike other `QIODevice` implementations, such as `QTcpSocket`, `QFile` does
>   not emit the `aboutToClose()`, `bytesWritten()`, or `readyRead()` signals.
>   This implementation detail means that `QFile` is not suitable for
>   reading and writing certain types of files, such as device files on
>   Unix platforms.

I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you shouldn't use `QFile` with files that may block on reading or writing, like device files (serial ports, for example). You should use instead another `QIODevice` derived class (maybe write your own), like `QExtSerialPort` does with serial port.